# What's the point of wrapping 'now' in a _now() function that returns 'now'?

Tags: solidity

Why people wrap 'now' in _now() function that just returns 'now'?

Found that on xDAI contracts:

```
function _now() internal view returns (uint256) {
    return now;
}
```

Is it because in 0.7.0 'now' was removed, and it's easier to make change in code in one place?
Or for testing timing? Or debugging, or smth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can override it in a test contract, and easily emulate time in a test script.

For example:

```
import "./xDAI.sol";

contract TestDAI is xDAI {
    uint256 public time = 1;

    function _now() internal view override returns (uint256) {
        return time;
    }

    function setTime(uint256 _time) public {
        time = _time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, just today I've decided to check the tests in xDAI - and yup - they do exactly that! :-D

Comment: @VictorNaumik: I actually thought about suggesting for you to check their github repo and search for the relevant test. But since you did not provide a link to that repo, I did not quite have it at hand in order to point you to the exact place in it.